# Updates Hidden on Dashboard

Tags: plugins, updates

I have taken over a website and it seems the plugin and core updates have been hidden.

I have checked the wp-config:

```
define( 'WP_AUTO_UPDATE_CORE', false );
```

and functions.php (for anything along these lines)

```
add_action('after_setup_theme','remove_core_updates');
function remove_core_updates()
{...
```

and checked there are no plugins which would do this.

I also did a manual update but it broke the website.

Is there anything I've missed?

**edit

ok so i tried a manual install on live and got an error in the wp-includes/load.php i had to do a restore from the host but it still means i am unable to update.

Thanks

Comment: Have you done the basics? Eg. check that you have proper Administrator permissions and then try disabling plugins one by one and switch to a different theme? That should help you isolate the issue...

Comment: The core files had been changed - i did a manual install of wordpress and they're back.  Wordfence had thrown up some core changes which was a red flag anyway.